# Lambda expression evaluation not working in Visual Studio 2015. Why?

Tags: c#, lambda, visual-studio-2015, immediate-window, watch-window

I was quite excited to test the lambda expression evaluation in Watch/Immediate window of VS2015, unfortunately I can't get this feature working.

I was testing this on few ASP.NET project(using .NET 4.6.1), but no matter what expression I type into Watch window, the message is still the same: `Expression cannot contain lambda expressions`. Colleague of mine is happily using this tool on the same projects since we received VS2015.

This is one from all lambda's:

```
private static void LinqTest()
    {
        List<int> list = new List<int> { 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6 };
        int lambda = list.First<int>(p => p == 2);
    }
```

This code returns 2 as expected but in Watch and Immediate window `list.First<int>(p => p == 2)` yields `Expression cannot contain lambda expressions` error.

I have been looking for some tips all around the internet, but I have never seen any pre-requirements, nor restrictions of this feature, so I was hoping someone can give me useful hint, which will avoid me from reinstalling Visual Studio completely (as I currently don't see no other option).

I am running Visual Studio 2015 Professional, Version 4.6.01038 on Windows 10.

Comment: Picture/code of what you're attempting is going to probably be necessary

Comment: @Adam, I hope one lamba will be enough, but I have the same problem with, in fact, any lambda expression I have tried so far.

Answer (score -1):

Set into lambda first value of this list equal 2

```
private static void LinqTest()
{
    List<int> list = new List<int> { 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6 };
    int lambda = list.First(p => p == 2);
}
```